# Real-time line chart with ChartJS using Ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to create a real-time (ECG type display) line chart. I have sensors that are streaming data and I need to show the live stream on 1-second interval. I only want to show 60 seconds of data on the chart so I need to pop the oldest label and data point. I can get the data to stream to the chart but I can't get the labels and data points to pop. Here is my code:

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('hashRateChart');

    var chartOptions = {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
                boxWidth: 20,
                fontColor: 'black'
            }
        }
    };

    var hashrateData = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Real Time Hash Rate",
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
            borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
            fill: false,
            data: []
        }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart( ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: hashrateData,
        options: chartOptions
    });

    function addData( chart, label, data ) {
        // pop last label and data point if we have 1 minutes data in chart
        if ( chart.data.labels.length >= 60 ) { removeData( chart) };

        chart.data.labels.push( label );
        chart.data.datasets.forEach(( dataset ) => {
            dataset.data.push( data );
        } );
        chart.update();
    }

    function removeData( chart, callback ) {
        chart.data.labels.pop();
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.pop();
        });
        chart.update();
    }

    ( function worker() {

        $.ajax( {
            url: "http://localhost:5000/stats?id=1",
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain: false,
            type: "GET",
            success: function( response ) {

                var r = $.parseJSON( response );
                var dte = new Date();

                addData( myChart, dte.getHours() + ":" + dte.getMinutes() + ":" + dte.getSeconds(), r['total_rate'] );

            },
            complete: function() {
                // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                setTimeout( worker, 1000 );
            }
        } );
    } )();
```

The chart keeps refreshing but the old datapoints remain. Ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using pop I think you are removing the last element in the list and not the oldest one. So after 60 seconds, only the last element will be updated and the older data will remain.

Use splice to remove the first element of the array in the `removeChart`

```js
   function removeData( chart, callback ) {
        chart.data.labels.splice(0, 1);
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.splice(0, 1);
        });
        chart.update();
    }
```